# Can´t Connect on Plugin Registration Tool Crm dynamics 2016 (On premise)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

I can´t login into Plugin Registration Tool (Crm 2016 on premise), i use server IP, and the name of the server, and credential of a user with System Administrator role.

When a not use a port (like 5555 or 443), the tool show me a list of my two organizations, but i select any one, i press acept, show the list again but empty (no organizations listed).

The implementation of Crm Server listening all for the port 443 in https.

Another behavior its occurs when a disable a organization, a let enable only a default organization (in other words, a enable a single organization), in this case i cant retrieve any organizations.

I test to navigate on web service, service detection, discovery and the test are succesfully.

Anyone can help about this issue

Thanks a lot

Comment: I test using Login Control Tester provided in CRM SDK 2016, in the "Bin" folder. I check the user and this have role permission in CRM and are Admon account of Domain, also the same user is using for the CRM´s associated services enter image description here

Answer (score 0):

Use the Organization Service URL from Developer Resources screen from within CRM.  Also make sure that your credentials are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I test using Login Control Tester provided in CRM SDK 2016, in the "Bin" folder. I check the user and this have role permission in CRM and are Admon account of Domain, also the same user is using for the CRM´s associated services 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vizBK.png)